# Remove space between childrens in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm developing an Android game for fun and I can't remove the space between my ImageViews in my LinearLayouts.
There isn't a defined number of ImageViews in these layouts, that's why I don't deal with XML files.
So I've created every ImageViews in my Java code and I've added them in my Layout.
But there is blank spaces between each of them : [Spaces between ImageViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQMm0.png) (Blue/red/green squares are ImageViews).
I started with a GridLayout to do that but I can't remove that blank space so I try with some LinearLayouts (Horizontal) into other LinearLayout (Vertical).

I've tried a lot of thing like setMargin and Padding to 0, create a LayoutParams to remove them, etc .. but it didn't work.

Thank you !

EDIT : here's my code

```
iv = new ImageView[cm.getNbRow()][cm.getNbColumn()];    //cm is the map object

LinearLayout[] linearTab = new LinearLayout[cm.getNbColumn()];
for(int i=0; i<cm.getNbRow(); i++) {
    linearTab[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearTab[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
}

for(int i=0; i<cm.getNbRow(); i++) {
    for(int ii = 0; ii < cm.getNbColumn(); ii++) {
        if(cm.getMap()[i][ii] == 1) {
            iv[i][ii] = new ImageView(this);
            iv[i][ii].setImageResource(R.drawable.wall);
        } else if(cm.getMap()[i][ii] == 2) {
            p = new Player(i, ii, this, cm);
            iv[i][ii] = new ImageView(this);
            iv[i][ii].setImageResource(R.drawable.player);
        } else if(cm.getMap()[i][ii] == 3) {
            iv[i][ii] = new ImageView(this);
            iv[i][ii].setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
        } else {
            iv[i][ii] = new ImageView(this);
            iv[i][ii].setImageResource(R.drawable.path);
        }
        linearTab[i].addView(iv[i][ii]);        //Horizontal LinearLayout
    }
    ll.addView(linearTab[i]);                   //Vertical LinearLayout
}
```

EDIT 2 : Android Studio adds transparents borders to the ImageViews (don't know why tho) but I've solved it by editing the generated image and coloring the transparents parts.

Comment: A code for adding the imageviews please!

Comment: please share your code

Comment: try `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

Comment: Code added. I tried `setScaleType()` but it doesn't work

Comment: @Rallph are you sure, that your drawables doesn't include empty space?

Comment: @DimaRostopira I'm sure, my drawables are 10*10 full colored images

Comment: My bad, I've just verified and I've imported 10*10 full colored png files, but AndroidStudio have converted them into 32*32 (mdpi), 48*48 (hdpi), 64*64 (xhdpi) and 96*96 (xxhdpi) files with transparent borders .... How do I remove that ? Or how can I make AndroidStudio stop adding these transparents borders ? http://imgur.com/a/JpWSh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import an image, you need to make sure that the option "Trim" is set to "yes" and "Padding" is set to 0%. That should ensure that the image doesn't have a transparent region around it.

Comment: Trim was set to "no" but even with it on "yes", it still set transparents borders to my images (padding at 0% or -10%)

Comment: @Rallph Then add the images manually. This may be a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: It works by editing the actuals ones and removing the border by myself

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`?

Comment: I haven't an XML file with my ImageViews and `myImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);` doesn't work

Comment: Try: `myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);` (do not remove adjustViewBounds)

Comment: I've also tried with a GridLayout but the problem didn't come from the layout